# SVG clipping mask disappear when changing angular states (Safari / Chrome)

Tags: angularjs, svg, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I'm making a logo out of an SVG.  Below is the code I am using to construct that logo.  It works well and good, with three stacked rectangles and a clipping mask I define.

What is super strange is that whenever I change states in my angular app the clipping mask disappears and I am left with just the rectangles.  In Chrome the clipping mask disappears when I zoom also.

Any input appreciated.

```
        <svg style="display:none;" class="gp-ui">
            <defs>
                <g id="gp_logo-text">
                    <g class="gp_logo-global">
                        <path fill="#fff" d="M568.7,485.5c4.6,19.3,23.5,28.5,41.7,28.5c12.9,0,24.8-4.2,34.1-13.5c10-10.2,10.9-20.8,10.9-34.5v-58.2h11.3v-19h-29.6v13c-6.5-10.3-17.3-14.5-29.1-14.5c-24.2,0-44.3,21.3-44.3,45.8c0,24.8,19.3,46,44.1,46c11.8,0,21.7-4.5,27.9-14.8v3.3c0,8.4-0.5,14-6,20.7c-4.4,5.2-11.6,8.2-18.5,8.2c-7.7,0-16.2-3.5-19.6-11L568.7,485.5L568.7,485.5L568.7,485.5z M584.2,433c0-14.8,11.9-27,26.5-27c14.5,0,26.6,12,26.6,26.8c0,15-11.4,27.5-26.5,27.5C596,460.4,584.2,448.2,584.2,433L584.2,433z" />
                        <polygon fill="#fff" points="694.6,358.8 663.5,358.8 663.5,377.8 674.7,377.8 674.7,458.9 662.6,458.9 662.6,477.9 705.9,477.9 705.9,458.9 694.6,458.9 " />
                        <path fill="#fff" d="M749.9,480.2c25.6,0,45.9-21.3,45.9-47.4c0-25.3-20.3-46.7-45.4-46.7c-25.3,0-46.1,20.8-46.1,46.9C704.3,458.7,724.4,480.2,749.9,480.2L749.9,480.2z M749.9,460.2c-14.9,0-26-12.7-26-27.4c0-14.8,12.1-26.7,26.5-26.7c14.5,0,25.8,12.7,25.8,27.2C776.1,448.2,764.4,460.2,749.9,460.2L749.9,460.2z" />
                        <path fill="#fff" d="M824.5,358.8h-31.2v19h11.3v81h-11.3v19h31.2v-13.3c6.7,9.7,17.6,14.7,29.2,14.7c11.4,0,23.2-5.8,30.9-14.5c7.7-8.5,11.8-19.8,11.8-31.3c0-25.2-20.3-45.9-44.9-45.9c-11.1,0-20.7,4.8-26.9,14.2L824.5,358.8L824.5,358.8L824.5,358.8zM850.1,406c14.5,0,26.4,12.2,26.4,27c0,14.5-11.3,27.3-26,27.3c-15,0-26.9-12-26.9-27.5C823.7,418,835.6,406,850.1,406L850.1,406z" />
                        <path fill="#fff" d="M973.1,477.9h31.2v-19h-10.9v-51h10.9v-19h-31.2v12.7c-6-9.7-15.8-15-27.1-15c-25.5,0-45.7,21.5-45.7,47.4c0,25.2,19.8,46.3,44.8,46.3c11.4,0,21.7-4.5,28.1-14.3L973.1,477.9L973.1,477.9z M946.8,460.4c-14.1,0-26-12-26-26.5c0-15,11.4-27.5,26.3-27.5c14.4,0,26.3,11.8,26.3,26.5C973.4,448,961.8,460.4,946.8,460.4L946.8,460.4z" />
                        <polygon fill="#fff" points="1040.9,358.8 1009.7,358.8 1009.7,377.8 1020.9,377.8 1020.9,458.9 1008.8,458.9 1008.8,477.9 1052.1,477.9 1052.1,458.9 1040.9,458.9 " />
                    </g>

                    <g class="gp_logo-post">

                        <path fill="#E62100" d="M1072.2,491.4h-11.1v19h42.5v-19h-11.3v-26c7,9.3,18.1,13.8,29.6,13.8c24.2,0,43.4-21.2,43.4-45.5c0-25.2-19.8-45.9-44.4-45.9c-11.8,0-22.2,4.8-28.6,15v-14h-31.2v19h11.1L1072.2,491.4L1072.2,491.4L1072.2,491.4z M1118.4,460.4c-14.5,0-26.3-12-26.3-26.8c0-15.3,12.1-27,26.8-27c14.5,0,25.8,12.7,25.8,27.2C1144.7,448.4,1132.8,460.4,1118.4,460.4L1118.4,460.4z" />
                        <path fill="#E62100" d="M1213.7,480.2c25.7,0,45.9-21.3,45.9-47.4c0-25.3-20.2-46.7-45.4-46.7c-25.3,0-46.1,20.8-46.1,46.9C1168.1,458.7,1188.2,480.2,1213.7,480.2L1213.7,480.2z M1213.7,460.2c-14.9,0-26-12.7-26-27.4c0-14.8,12.1-26.7,26.5-26.7c14.5,0,25.8,12.7,25.8,27.2C1240,448.2,1228.2,460.2,1213.7,460.2L1213.7,460.2z" />
                        <path fill="#E62100" d="M1263.3,452v25.8h15.2v-7.3c5.7,6.8,13.7,9.7,22.5,9.7c16.3,0,31.2-10,31.2-28c0-20-16.8-25-32.5-28.7c-6.4-1.5-14.4-3.3-14.4-11.7c0-6.2,5.7-9.3,11.1-9.3c6.2,0,11,4.2,11.3,10.5h19.3v-24.2h-14.7v6.2c-4.9-6.3-11.9-8-19.8-8c-15.5,0-29.6,9.8-29.6,26.8c0,19.5,16.7,24.4,31.8,28.4c6.7,1.8,14.9,3.3,14.9,12.2c0,6.7-5.9,11-11.9,11c-8.2,0-13.4-5.3-14.1-13.3L1263.3,452L1263.3,452L1263.3,452z" />
                        <polygon fill="#E62100" points="1368.3,407.8 1383.2,407.8 1383.2,388.8 1368.3,388.8 1368.3,358.8 1348.4,358.8 1348.4,388.8 1334.7,388.8 1334.7,407.8 1348.4,407.8 1348.4,477.9 1384.2,477.9 1384.2,458.9 1368.3,458.9 " />
                    </g>
                </g>
                <path id="gp_logo-swoosh-path" d="M565.9,316v21c64.4-24.4,147.2-39.3,237.5-39.2c90.2,0,173,14.8,237.5,39.2v-21
                        c-66-23.9-148.2-38-237.5-38C714.1,278,631.9,292.1,565.9,316" />
            </defs>
         </svg>

         <svg id="globalpost_logo" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="563.8 277.9 820.4 236.1" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g id="gp_logo-swoosh" ng-class="{'gp_logo-loading': uiCtrl.loadingState}" clip-path="url(#gp_logo-clip-path)">
                        <clipPath id="gp_logo-clip-path" >
                            <use xlink:href="#gp_logo-swoosh-path" />
                        </clipPath>
                        <g id="gp_logo-swoosh">
                            <rect id="gp_logo-swoosh-lead-rect" class="active" x="565.9" y="277.9" fill=" rgba(69, 125, 222, 0)" width="1em" height="59" />
                            <rect id="gp_logo-swoosh-fill-rect" x="565.9" y="277.9" fill=" rgba(69, 125, 222, 0)" width="1em" height="59" />
                            <rect id="gp_logo-swoosh-full-rect" x="565.9" y="277.9" fill=" rgba(69, 125, 222, 1)" width="1em" height="59" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <use xlink:href="#gp_logo-text" />
         </svg>
```

Comment: Are you setting/using a `<base>` tag. There are lots of questions and answers already about working around this.

Comment: Many thanks, this is a good discussion:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8934

This is a module that also helps:
https://github.com/jeffbcross/angular-svg-base